# replace a particular text after N-th occurrence of a character

Tags: text-processing, replace

I want to replace the numbers in below file with `#Mi`.

Only for numbers after the 10th occurrence of `"` (double quote)

Input File

```
"col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col5" #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi 1002.47 1018.81 1016.68 
"col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col5" #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi 501.24 509.41 508.34 
"col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col5" #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi 55.69 56.6 56.48
```

Output File

```
"col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col5" #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi 
"col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col5" #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi 
"col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col5" #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi #Mi
```

Comment: the below option version 5.10.0 does the job.... Awesome ! Thanks so much !

Not sure how it works, if you could please elaborate. 
Sorry to bother, I am new to perl and trying to learn.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
<your-file sed '
  s/"/"\
/10;                          # add a newline after the 10th "
  h;                          # save a copy
  s/.*\n//;                   # remove everything before the newline
  s/[0-9.]\{1,\}/#Mi/g;       # replace numbers with #Mi
  G;                          # append saved copy
  s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n.*/\2\1/; # put it back together'
```

With `perl` (5.14.0 or above for the `r` substitution flag):

```
perl -pe 's{(.*?"){10}\K.*}{$& =~ s/[\d.]+/#Mi/gr}e' < your-file
```

With older versions (but still at least 5.10.0 for `\K`):

```
perl -pe 's{(.*?"){10}\K.*}{($r = $&) =~ s/[\d.]+/#Mi/g; $r}e' < your-file
```

With even older versions:

```
perl -pe 's{((?:.*?"){10})(.*)}{
  $l = $1; ($r = $2) =~ s/[\d.]+/#Mi/g; $l.$r}e' < your-file
```

In both *numbers* is any sequence of one or more digits or `.`. You may want to refine the pattern to avoid it matching on things like `127.0.0.1` or `...` or `.` anywhere in case such things may occur in the input past the 10<sup>th</sup> `"`. For instance, in `perl`, that could be `(?<!\S)\d+\.\d+(?!\S)`: digits-dot-digits neither preceded nor followed by non-whitespace.

On your sample, even

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\S)\d+\.\d+(?!\S)/#Mi/g' < you-file
```

would be enough as the part before the 10<sup>th</sup> `"` doesn't have any of those *digits-dot-digits* non-surrounded by non-whitespace. It all boils down to what you want to be substituted and what may occur in your input that you *don't* want to be substituted.

Comment: Tried using perl.. It throws below error:


Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/[\d.]+/#Mi/gr"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/[\d.]+/#Mi/gr
"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: could you please help with more information on the sed command

Comment: @Parix, is it possible that your perl is older than 5.14.0 (released in 2011)?

Comment: yes.. the version is v5.10.1

Comment: @Parix, see edit for older versions of perl.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` we do it as follows. Mark the 10th occurrence of a double quote with a `\n` since it can never be present in the line as it is stripped away by the `-l` option.

---

```
$ perl -lpe '
    s/((?:.*?"){10})/$1\n/;
    s/(?<!\S)\d+\.\d+(?!\S)(?!.*\n)/#Mi/g;
    tr/\n//d;
' file
```

---

```
$ d='[[:digit:]]' f="$d$d*[.]$d$d*" r='#Mi' 
$ sed -Ee "
    s/\"/&\n/10
    :loop
       s/(\n.*\s)$f(\s|\$)/\1$r\2/
    t loop
    s/\n//
" file
```

---

Comment: Note that in sed, `\n` on the RHS and `\s` are GNU extensions (of sed and glibc respectively). -E is a NetBSD extension, relatively recently (2009) added to GNU `sed`.